# should i quit my job? (currently a full stack web dev intern)

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, quitting

I was recently hired as a full stack intern by a small manufacturing company with the goal of creating an eCommerce platform to allow manufacturers to network with distributors.

That's great and all but I am the sole person in charge of this project, I have no superior who is knowledgeable in computer science. I'm still not done with college, an I don't have a ton of experience with web development so more than half my job for the past two weeks has been watching a ton of youtube tutorials, and reading stack overflow to try to to understand what I'm trying to do.the boss let me pick the framework so I went with asp.net and mysql because those would be the things I'm most familiar with but the scope of this project sounds unreasonable to me.

My boss recently showed me a products sheet with collums a -cz. While thats easy enought to import to a database I'm not sure its organized correctly and im pretty sure I should reorganize that file if I use it (currently arranged in single table I think I want some inheritance in there do get some smaller tables.). I also haven't had a database class yet though I have had limited use of them in past school assignments. However I haven't yet secured a backup and this is the summer before my senior year and I haven't had an internship yet. The pay for me right now is also below minimum wage (1000 per a month). anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: so far Ive been able to make gradual progress and learn what I need to know about front end web dev. but I'm concerned that now that I got to database back end, the scope of the project may be beyond me. bigger problem so far all my boss has done so far is show me a paper copy of the csv and he hasnt given me access to it (its been 2 days), so II can either type line by line from the csv or watch tutorials wand wait wondering how this is gonna playout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the real world.   That's how a lot of companies operate. Not saying it's good....but that's just the truth of it.    They likely tried to cheap out and didn't think they needed to hire an experienced developer, thinking this was just a small project.

You're an intern.  The point of an internship is to learn and get some experience in the real world, and to be able to list it on your resume after you graduate and look for a permanent position.

Do the best you can, and be honest with your boss that you're learning as you go. Watch tutorials, make heavy use of the internet, blogs and Stackexchange.

The truth of it is that you will not do as good of a job as a senior developer, or even someone with several years experience.    If your boss isn't happy with that, he should have hired an experienced developer instead of an intern.   Don't feel bad for not doing as good of a job as someone else might.    We all look back on our first jobs and cringe at how little we knew.   That's just the nature of it.

Comment: to be clear youre saying i should stick it out and try my best

Comment: Yes.    I am.   This is, by nature, a temp job.   Do your best, learn from the experience, and move on.   You'll learn as a developer, and as grow as an employee.

Comment: They are paying you to try and figure it out. That's half of the point of an internship; to be a learning experience for you. What's the worst that could happen if you guess wrong? To try again?